# How to get first n chars from a str column in python polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

What's the alternative of pandas :

```
data['ColumnA'].str[:2]
```

in python polars?

```
pl.col('ColumnA').str[:3]
```

throws `TypeError: 'ExprStringNameSpace' object is not subscriptable`

error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`str.slice`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.slice.html), It takes two arguments `offset` and `length`. `offset` specifies the *start index* and the `length` specifies the *length of slice. If set to `None` (default), the slice is taken to the end of the string*.

```
>>> import polars as pl
>>> 
>>> df = pl.DataFrame({"animal": ["Crab", "cat and dog", "rab$bit", None]})
>>> df
shape: (4, 1)
┌─────────────┐
│ animal      │
│ ---         │
│ str         │
╞═════════════╡
│ Crab        │
│ cat and dog │
│ rab$bit     │
│ null        │
└─────────────┘
>>> df.with_columns(pl.col("animal").str.slice(0, 3).alias("sub_string"))
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────────────┬────────────┐
│ animal      ┆ sub_string │
│ ---         ┆ ---        │
│ str         ┆ str        │
╞═════════════╪════════════╡
│ Crab        ┆ Cra        │
│ cat and dog ┆ cat        │
│ rab$bit     ┆ rab        │
│ null        ┆ null       │
└─────────────┴────────────┘
```